# Is there an easy way to make a Jackson ObjectMapper deserialize from an Iterator<Pair<JsonToken, String>>?

Tags: java, json, jackson

For complicated reasons, my raw input is a bunch of Pair < JsonToken, String >. Is there a way to get my Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize JSON from this form? I guess if I could convert that to a JsonNode tree or a JsonParser it would work. Making my own implementation of JsonParser looks painful though.

Comment: What exactly does your JSON look like?  Pair isn't even a standard type.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to build a `TokenBuffer` out of those; and since it implements both `JsonParser` and `JsonGenerator`, it can be passed to the rest of functionality.